# I get a TypeError while doing sentiment analysis, how can I fix this issue?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, typeerror, sentiment-analysis

I am doing Sentiment Analysis on Bitcoin News. During my coding a TypeError Problem occured. I hope you can help me and thank you very much in advance!

```
from newsapi.newsapi_client import NewsApiClient
from textblob import TextBlob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
from datetime import time
import csv
from dateutil import parser

api = NewsApiClient(api_key='my key')

all_articles = api.get_everything(q='bitcoin',
                                      sources='bbc-news,the-verge,financial-times,metro,business-insider,reuters,bloomberg,cnbc,cbc-news,fortune,crypto-coins-news',
                                      domains='bbc.co.uk,techcrunch.com',
                                      from_param='2019-10-20',
                                      to='2019-11-19',
                                      language='en',
                                      sort_by='relevancy',
                                      page_size=100)

news= pd.DataFrame(all_articles['articles'])

news['polarity'] = news.apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x['description']).sentiment.polarity, axis=1)
news['subjectivity'] = news.apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x['description']).sentiment.subjectivity, axis=1)
news['date']= news.apply(lambda x: parser.parse(x['publishedAt']).strftime('%Y.%m.%d'), axis=1)
news['time']= news.apply(lambda x: parser.parse(x['publishedAt']).strftime('%H:%M'), axis=1)
```

Then this TypeError occurs:
[imgur_link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0RML.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Hayat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8868699/hayat) correctly pointed out, some of the rows in `description` column have `None` values which are causing the exception. There are four such rows, see the screenshot below.

[image: Rows with <code>None</code> in <code>description</code> column]

You should remove such rows and operate on the ones that have proper data. You can filter rows that have `None` in `description` column using

```
news_filtered = news[news['description'].notnull()]
news_filtered['polarity'] = news_filtered.apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x['description']).sentiment.polarity, axis=1)
```

You may have to repeat the above for other columns.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I tried the code and again came across an error message again...                           
C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: That's a warning, you can ignore for now.

Comment: ok thanks, it works now but the Problem is that after filtering there are only 19 artlices left instead of 100 at the beginning, does that mean that 81 descriptions have Non values in them?

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, there are only 4 rows that have `description` as None, rest 96 rows have proper values. Check if you are missing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug your code. You are passing `None` value.

`x['description']` might have some `None` value in there.

```
news['polarity'] = news.apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x['description']).sentiment.polarity, axis=1)
```

Make sure in your preprocessing stage you don't have any `None` or `NaN` value in your `dataframe`